# sending and receiving SMS using PIC18f4550 + GSM sim300

Tags: gsm, pic

I want to send & receive SMS using GSM sim300 modem  and Micro_controller ( PIC18f4550 )
I've tested the GSM with PC (HyperTerminal) and it was working great.
but now I've wrote a small code so that I can send and receive using micro_controller, but it doesn't send anything ! I don't know where is the problem in the code.
please give it a look and help me.

Jan,

```
#include<p18f4550.h>
#include<delays.h>

#pragma config PLLDIV = 3
#pragma config CPUDIV = OSC1_PLL2
#pragma config FOSC = HS
#pragma config MCLRE = ON
#pragma config WDT = OFF , DEBUG = OFF
#pragma config LVP = OFF
#pragma config PWRT = OFF 
#pragma config PBADEN = OFF

///////////////////////////////////

 //    defining PORTs  
 //---------------------------------
#define ldata PORTD    
#define rs PORTCbits.RC0
#define rw PORTCbits.RC1
#define en PORTCbits.RC2
#define send PORTBbits.RB1  //for sending 
#define rec PORTBbits.RB2  // for receiving

void lcdcmd(unsigned char value)
{
ldata = value;
rs = 0;
rw = 0;
en = 1;
Delay100TCYx( 30 );
en = 0;
}


//Defining the LCD display
//------------------------------------------
void lcddata(unsigned char value)
{
ldata = value;
rs = 1;
rw = 0;
en = 1;
Delay100TCYx( 30 );
en = 0;
}


// LCD initialization 


void lcd_ini()
{
lcdcmd(0x38);   //LCD matrix
Delay10KTCYx( 75 );
lcdcmd(0x0E);   //Blink curser
Delay10KTCYx( 4 );
lcdcmd(0x01);   //Clear LCD
Delay10KTCYx( 4 );
lcdcmd(0x06);     //increment curser
Delay10KTCYx( 4 );
lcdcmd(0x80); //start at firs line, first position
Delay10KTCYx( 4 );
}



// define serial communication ( receiving data from GPS)
//---------------------------------------
unsigned char rx_data(void); //receiving data function
void tx_data(unsigned char serial_data);     // Transmit data function

void display( unsigned char array[], int size); // to display any string on LCD
void transmit( unsigned char array2[], int size2); // to send any string to TX pin

unsigned char ch=0;
int i=0,j,k;
unsigned char welcome[]=" Welcome ";
unsigned char choice[]="Send or receive? "; 
unsigned char sending[]=" Sending .. ";
unsigned char waiting[]=" Waiting for SMS";
unsigned char sms_received[]=" SMS Received ";
unsigned char character_set[]="AT+CSCS=\"GSM\"\r";

unsigned char sms_format[]="AT+CMGF=1\r";   // TEXT mode
unsigned char sms_write[]="AT+CMGS=\"XXXXXXXXXX\"\r";  // 10-Digit Mobile Number
unsigned char sms[]="Hello\r";
unsigned char sms_report[]="SMS Sent...";
unsigned char sms_indication[]="AT+CNMI=1,2,0,0,0\r";

unsigned char stringArray[6]; //to store the received sms information
unsigned char sms_terminate=0x1A;  //Ctrl+z
unsigned char enter=0x0D;  // Enter Key


// ** The Main Function **


void main()
{

TRISD = 0;  //Set it output for the LCD
TRISCbits.RC0 = 0; //Set it output for RS
TRISCbits.RC1 = 0; //Set it output for RW
TRISCbits.RC2 = 0; //Set it output for en
TRISBbits.RB1 = 1; // To send an SMS
TRISBbits.RB2= 1; // To Receive an SMS


// serial communicatin configuration 

SPBRG= 18; //Fill SPBRG register to set the baud rate
RCSTAbits.SPEN=1;     // To activate Serial port (TX and RX pins)
TXSTAbits.TXEN=1;      // To enable transmission
RCSTAbits.CREN=1;  // To enable continuous reception
PIR1bits.RCIF =0; // clear rcif interrupt flag
PIE1bits.RCIE=1;
INTCONbits.PEIE =1; // enable peripheral interrupt
INTCONbits.GIE =1; // enable global interrupt


lcd_ini();  // LCD Initializing
Delay10KTCYx( 250);

  display( welcome, sizeof(welcome)); //display " Welcome "
  Delay10KTCYx( 250);
 Delay10KTCYx( 250);
     Delay10KTCYx( 250);



   while(1)
   {      
      lcdcmd(0x01); // clear LCD
      lcdcmd(0x80); // Start at first line first position
 Delay10KTCYx( 250);
      display( choice, sizeof(choice)); // display " Send or Receive ? "
      Delay10KTCYx( 250);


          if(send==1) // if sending switch is pressed 
            {
             lcdcmd(0x01);
             lcdcmd(0x80);
             Delay10KTCYx( 250);
             display(sending, sizeof(sending)); // display "sending.."
             Delay10KTCYx( 250);

             transmit(sms_format, sizeof(sms_format)); // send to GSM ( set Text mode)
              Delay10KTCYx( 250);
              Delay10KTCYx( 250);
             transmit(character_set, sizeof(character_set)); // send to GSM 
                Delay10KTCYx( 250);
                Delay10KTCYx( 250);
             transmit(sms_write, sizeof(sms_write)); // send to GSM ( to write phone number)
              Delay10KTCYx( 250);
              Delay10KTCYx( 250);
              Delay10KTCYx( 250);
              Delay10KTCYx( 250);
              Delay10KTCYx( 250);
             transmit(sms, sizeof(sms));  // send to GSM ( to write the sms)  
             tx_data(sms_terminate);  // ctrl+z

             Delay10KTCYx( 250);
            Delay10KTCYx( 250);
              tx_data(enter);  // enter Key
              lcdcmd(0x01);
             lcdcmd(0x80);
             Delay10KTCYx( 250);
             display(sms_report, sizeof(sms_report)); // display "SMS Sent .."
            Delay10KTCYx( 250);
            Delay10KTCYx( 250);

               }  

        if(rec==1) //if Receiving switch is pressed 
          {

             lcdcmd(0x01);
             lcdcmd(0x80);
             Delay10KTCYx( 250);
             display(waiting, sizeof(waiting)); // display " waiting for sms"
             transmit(sms_format, sizeof(sms_format)); // to set the mode           
             Delay10KTCYx( 250);
             Delay10KTCYx( 250);
             Delay10KTCYx( 250);

             transmit(sms_indication, sizeof(sms_indication)); // to choose how sms arrive
              Delay10KTCYx( 250);
             Delay10KTCYx( 250);
             Delay10KTCYx( 250);

             ch= rx_data();  /* read char from serial port */
               for(k=0; k<46; k++)
             {
                  stringArray[k] = ch;
             }





            // --- By this point the SMS is Received and stored in Array --

                lcdcmd(0x01);
             lcdcmd(0x80);
             Delay10KTCYx( 250);
             display(sms_received, sizeof(sms_received)); // display ( sms received )
              Delay10KTCYx( 250);
              Delay10KTCYx( 250);



             /*--- display SMS on LCD ---*/
               lcdcmd(0x01);
             lcdcmd(0x80);
             Delay10KTCYx( 250);
             display(stringArray, sizeof(stringArray)); // display the text that received
              Delay10KTCYx( 250);
              Delay10KTCYx( 250);



        }
} //end while1


}// end main function

//------ methods ---------

unsigned char rx_data(void)  //Receive data from RX pin
{
while(PIR1bits.RCIF==0); // Wait until RCIF gets low
return RCREG; // Store data in Reception register
}

void tx_data(unsigned char serial_data)      // Transmit data through TX pin
{
   TXREG=serial_data;
   while(PIR1bits.TXIF==0);
}

void display( unsigned char array[], int size)  //to display any string on LCD
{
    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
      {
         lcddata(array[i]);
      }
}

void transmit( unsigned char array2[], int size2) // to send strings to tx_data method
{
    for(i=0; i<size2; i++)
     {
       tx_data(array2[i]);
        Delay10KTCYx( 250);
     }
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that you're actually sending data on USART with correct baud rate?

Comment: Some log output would be useful for us to help you

Answer (score 0):

Two things...

Never assume the modem has done something without reading it's response. Send a command, then confirm by reading it's response. For instance; you "send and sms" but do not ping the modem for response. Does the program sit idle after you initiate the send SMS command? Do you see it respond with +OK?

Also, you need to send the equivalent to CTRL-Z not \r to send an SMS.